# Roles vs ACLs in spring

Tags: java, spring, acl, roles

The Question is should I use roles with object scopes or just use ACLs

Here is the use case, Lets say I want a User to have CRUD permissions on a companyA but only have Read permission on companyB.

Now I can implement this in two ways.

Method #1)

Create two Roles
1) ROLE_ADMIN :  A user in this role will have all CRUD permissions with respect to any company.

2) ROLE_SUPPORT : A user in this role has only read permissions at class (company) level e

Now I can say,

UserA--> has ROLE_ADMIN --on CompanyA
UserA--> has ROLE_SUPPPORT --on CompanyB.
Note: Here I am not putting any permissions on the object.

Method #2)
Have only one Role [Administrator] and I can say

UserA--> has CRUD permissions --on CompanyA
UserA--> has R[Read] permissions--on CompanyB

I am not sure which method is preferred and why. In the method #2) I see no value in Role as permissions are defined on object anyway. The only case I see it make sense is for CREATE. User would not know upfront if he allowed to create as the object does not exist by then.
In method 2, I would not need any multiple roles. but it does not sound right.

So now why should I use method #2 when I can do the same thing using method 1.

looking fwd to hear from you.

thanks
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roles and ACL serves different purposes.

Roles are to restrict to certain resources, for example you may say UserA can access companies or not.

With ACL instead you could say UserA has access to CompanyA but not CompanyB within the companies.

Therefore Roles are less granular than ACL but they can work together.

Back to your case, you will need ACL to restrict UserA to have Read for CompanyA and Write for CompanyB but Roles to say that UserA can access the resource of type company.
This will also solve the other issue about creation: because UserA can access companies, he could create a new CompanyC and by definition an ACL Write access will be associated to CompanyC (as he is the creator).